# Insert default value to SQL select statment

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert a default value to my select statement So I am doing it in this fashion.

Is there any better way I can do this?

I need to insert "All" as my first row value to table Sitetbl select statement.

```
 DECLARE @SiteValue TABLE  
 (  
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
    SiteID Nvarchar(15),  
    SiteName Nvarchar(100)  
 )  

 Insert into  @SiteValue(SiteID,SiteName) values('All','All')

 insert into  @SiteValue(SiteID,SiteName) 

 SELECT  DISTINCT  SiteID,SiteName from Sitetbl
```

Ex:
Result how I am looking

```
All  All
St   Singapore
IN   India
CH   China
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it like following.

```
insert into @SiteValue(SiteID,SiteName)
SELECT 'All' SiteID,'All' SiteName 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SiteID,SiteName from Sitetbl
```

Answer (score 0):

No.   There are other ways, such as using a UNION ALL in your SELECT, but they are not "better" than the way you are doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, introduction of the view:

```
CREATE VIEW SitetblWithDefault
AS
SELECT 'All' SiteID,'All' SiteName 
UNION ALL
SELECT  SiteID,SiteName from Sitetbl
```

So, all selects of this view will have Default value just before other values